# Rights regarding airline schedule change on Air France

Tags: cancellations, refunds

With reference to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66494/rights-regarding-airline-schedule-change) (which had clearly stated conditions), I booked a roundtrip flight from Hungary to Tunisia on Air France and the departure flight was cancelled. They automatically placed me on a flight that leaves three hours earlier when no public transit is running.

To my knowledge the Conditions of Carriage do not specify whether this is acceptable. Am I entitled to a refund according to Air France or EU regulations?

Comment: How long between the change and the departure?

Comment: In other words: How far in advance of the date of travel did the airline inform you about the change?

Comment: Months, but apparently I learned that the time between change and departure is not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that EU regulations require that the customer be able to choose between rebooking or a refund when a flight is cancelled, a fact which the airlines conveniently obscured when automatically rebooking me. When I finally got a response, they immediately agreed and I found an Alitalia flight that was more convenient and cheaper anyhow.